# What is the new AZ command to get logic app list using Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I can get we apps using the Az cmdlets by using **az webapp list**.
I have logic apps , I tried using az logicapp list
but its not recognised in Powershell.
Is there a manual listing the cmdlets to list logic apps ,sqlservers and sqldatabases ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the AZ cli equivalent of `Get-AzLogicApp` is the following:

```
az resource list  --resource-type 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows'
```

there are no dedicated cmdlets for managing logic apps in Az cli yet.

Comment: I can run it in powershell , but there is no Kind field. I want to run the equivalent of az cmdlet in cmd console  ?

Comment: why do you need a kind field? this returns only logic apps

Comment: I ran the az webapp cmdlet above to return websites, it doesn't return logic apps.  I was wondering of there was one for logic apps , like az logicapp .

Comment: I am after the AZ CLI equivalent of Get-AzLogicApp?

Comment: oh, ic now. this was absolutely not clear from your question, as both the answers are telling the same thing. let me update the answer

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to provide an update to @4c74356b41's answer since it has been almost 3 years. For the Azure CLI there are now (as of at least June 2022) commands for managing Logic Apps, both of the "standard" and "consumption" varieties.

For "standard" Logic Apps you can manage them with the `az logicapp` command. E.g.:

```
az logicapp list --resource-group MyResourceGroup
```

For all the operations, run `az logicapp --help`.

For "consumption" Logic Apps, there is a (currently in preview) command of `az logic workflow` that requires a logic extension to be installed for the Azure CLI. E.g.:

```
az logic workflow list --resource-group MyResourceGroup
```

For all the operations, run `az logic workflow --help`.

@4c74356b41's answer is definitely still valid, but better support for managing Logic Apps is now a part of the Azure CLI (which is also not directly tied to PowerShell as indicated by the OP's question...the Azure CLI does not have to be run in PowerShell).

See Microsoft's official docs for these Azure CLI commands (and others) at:

- [Standard Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/logicapp?view=azure-cli-latest)
- [Consumption Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/logic/workflow?view=azure-cli-latest)

Answer (score 0):

You could use below method to get logic app list.

```
Get-AzResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Logic/workflows" -ResourceGroupName  resourcegroupname
```

[image]

As for the sqlservers and sqldatabase, you could just use the method provided.
[Get-AzSqlDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/get-azsqldatabase?view=azps-2.7.0) and [Get-AzSqlServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/get-azsqlserver?view=azps-2.7.0) support to list the servers and the databases.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work . I have to use something like the following                           az resource show  --name 'myname' -g 'myresourcegroup' --resource-type 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows'

Comment: What's the `name`? Logic app name?

Comment: I have got it listed with the above cmdlet. But I cant understand why Get-AzLogicApp doesn't work .

Comment: Check the [Get-AzLogicApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.logicapp/Get-AzLogicApp?view=azps-2.7.0) description, it say **Gets a logic app from a resource group**. So it  returns only a Workflow object

Comment: @Mel, If you have solved it with my way please accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried numerous times , I cant see any acceptance available for me to do

Comment: You can't get logic app list with `Get-AzResource`?